# Using ProFiles Joomla Web Filemanager - it runs only with administrator rights

Tags: component, joomla-user-groups

I want to use the Joomla component "ProFiles". I want to setup a usergroup which can up/download files. How must iI implement the call to the component - the way I'm doing it is as follows: https://websiteabcd.xx/administrator/index.php?option=com_profiles&format=raw

This works only for SuperUsers. Is it possible to implement this component for a configured usergroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  I had not used this component before, so I installed it in a test environment and confirmed it works. Here are the steps I went through:

1. Create a new user under the Joomla! user group named 'Manager'
2. In the ProFiles component, navigate to 'Root folders & rights' > 'Rights' > 'Manager', and set the values to 'Allowed'
3. Login as your new user under the administrator login and navigate to the ProFiles component.

After completing these steps I turned off access, logged in again with my Manager account, and was met with the Joomla! error, "You are not authorized for this action!"

Comment: Very good - in my case, after i've done the same, i still got the login popUp rather dann the ProFile screen. Can you tell my how your link to the ProFile-Component looks like?

Comment: I navigate through the administrator view to the ProFile component, so the link is: http://localhost/joomla3/administrator/index.php?option=com_profiles

Comment: okay - that was it! Thanks alot

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer so it shows as completed